# Does JMM guarantees that volatile overwrites with the same value will be eventually visible?

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, volatile

JMM have guarantees that when thread A writes to volatile variable V all other (non-volatile) writes become visible to thread B after it reads that V value.

Does that guarantee holds in presence of multiple volatile V overwrites **with the same value**?

I.e. considering following code:

```java
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
volatile int v = 0;

void fromThreadA() {
    x = 1;
    v = 0;

    y = 1;
    v = 0; // note that both writes to v never actually change its value
}

void fromThreadB() {
    while(v == 0) {
      if (x == 1 && y == 1) break;
    }
}
```

is there guarantees that caller of `fromThreadB` will eventually terminate?

Comment: It will eventually terminate because of the second volatile write.

Comment: @BurakSerdar so it is not possible that second volatile write will be optimized away under JMM rules?

Comment: That's the point of volatile writes. They establish a happened-before relationship. The compiler knows not to reorder memory operations through volatile writes, and by definition, cannot optimize them.

Comment: The language specification says a write to a volatile value followed by a read of that same value.  It says nothing about what the data written actually is.  I didn't read through the spec again but I'm sure Burak is correct, it should key-off the write, not the value.

Comment: What difference would it make either way? If the value isn't changing, how would you observe whether the write had taken effect or not? What is the actual question here?

Comment: @user207421 the question exactly is, if I can't observe the (volatile) change of the value, is there guarantees that I will observe side-effects (i.e. releasing of previous writes) of this change?

Comment: @user207421, `volatile` isn't really about "seeing the most up-to-date value" of the `volatile` variable. That's just a side-benefit from the real purpose of `volatile` which is, to establish a "happens before" relationship between events in two different threads. In this case, the OP is asking whether it still establishes that relationship even in the case where the `volatile` assignment doesn't actually change the value of the variable.